# Custom implementation of getCurrentAuditor method returns error when trying to use a JPA repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, auditing

I have a user entity with an audit field named `lastUpdatedUserId` (same as `LastModifiedBy`). This is an integer field. I'm trying to use the auditing feature provided by Spring and did everything stated in the docs. When I tried to override the `getCurrentAuditor` method of `AuditorAware`, it works fine if I hardcode an integer as the return value. If I try to use `UserRepository` (a Spring Data JPA repository) to get the user id of the logged in user, I get a `Could not commit JPA transaction` error. I'm using Gmail Oauth2 for authentication.
The stacktrace is too long for me to post here. I tried to debug, but it has not been easy.

If any of you know the reason, please let me know.

```java
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User {
    @LastModifiedBy
  @Column(name = "lst_updtd_usr_id")
  private Integer lastUpdatedUserId;
    ...
}

 public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Integer> {
  
      @Autowired
      private UserRepository userRepo;
  
       @Override
       public Optional<Integer> getCurrentAuditor() {
        // your custom logic
      
      DefaultOidcUser oidcUser = (DefaultOidcUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String emailId = oidcUser.getEmail();
    User user = userRepo.findByEmailId(emailId);
      return Optional.of(user.getUserId());
       }

    }

 @Configuration 
 @EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef="auditorP")
    public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    AuditorAware<Integer> auditorP() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The population of auditing fields happens in JPA lifecycle events.
When handling such events one is not allowed to use the `EntityManager`, which you do when you try to use a Spring Data JPA repository.

As a workaround you could:

1. Load the required version before the events get triggered and keep it in some request scope variable.
2. Use JDBC directly to access the database to obtain the information.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens. I got it to work by adding it to the request scope.